# Django detective spots POST requests

Tags: django

I installed django-detective last night and today there are many weird post requests in it.

It looks like somebody is trying to post stuff like this on my website:

```
/wp-admin/admin-post.phpnd_stats_value_import_settings=home[nd_stats_option_value]https://dodgylookingsite.com/pret
```

**Please do not go to this link as I think it might be hosting malware !!**

What does this mean? 
How can I prevent this from happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this looks for known WordPress vulnerabilities (wp-admin).